# How to calculate a week number for a given date SQL

Tags: mysql

How can I calculate a week number using SQL command ?
For an instance, for this date: 2017-01-05 I should see this week - WK1.

Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you use the [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)?

Comment: This question demonstrates no research effort. You should always try to solve your problem and include the code relating to your attempt, before asking the community on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search on the mysql website would have given you this information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

The syntax is

```
  select week('2017-01-05') as week_number
```

Or if you want to create the string specified in your question

```
  select concat('WK', week('2017-01-05')) as week_number
```